# Getting html out of multiple input labels with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, input

So this is my code so far...

```
function doAlertings()
  {
     var inputlabels = $('.inputLabel').each(function(i, obj) {

   });
  alert(inputlabels);
  }
```

This will alert all 12 of my input labels one after another however they are all blank. But when I use...

```
var inputlabels = $('.inputLabel').html();
alert(inputlabels);
```

That will alert only the first input label and stop there. Anyone got an idea of how to get the html out of each one?

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use jQuery.each() method.

Comment: USe  $('.inputLabel').each(function(i, obj) {alert($(this).html() });

Comment: Use `$.each( $('.inputLabel'),function(){alert($(this).html() });`

Comment: Thank you guys problem is solved.

Comment: So i'm using that technique now, however at the end of the loop i get an 'object object' alert too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)`.text() to get the text of each element in **[each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** loop

```
$('.inputLabel').each(function(i, obj) {
    alert($(this).html()); // console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to indentation - messy indentation and formatting makes code obscure and you easily overlook a mistake, like in your case.

After you format your code properly, you get:

```
function doAlertings()
{
    var inputlabels = $('.inputLabel').each(function(i, obj) {
        // do nothing
    });

    alert(inputlabels);
}
```

So, you clearly see, you are calling the alert function just once.

If your intent is to alert contents of the labels, this would be the way:

```
function doAlertings()
{
    var inputlabels = $('.inputLabel').each(function(i, obj) {
        alert( $(obj).html() );
    });
}
```